# ESP32-S3 reading serial messages from Arduino

Tags: arduino, usb, serial, esp32

I am trying to get serial data from my custom-built ESP32-Wroom-S3 board in the Arduino IDE

The PCB works. I can program it from the Arduino IDE and make the LEDs blink.

- Schematics: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll/main/PCB/schematics-v22-jlcpcb/readme-media/board-schematics.svg)
- Layout: [link](https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll/raw/main/PCB/schematics-v22-jlcpcb/readme-media/board-pcb.jpg)

[image]

I have the simplest possible code, so I don't think that is the problem

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Loop");
  digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW)
  delay(1000);
}
```

In the serial console of the Arduino IDE I only get:

```
ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x15 (USB_UART_CHIP_RESET),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x4037d23e
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3808,len:0x44c
load:0x403c9700,len:0xbec
load:0x403cc700,len:0x2920
entry 0x403c98d8
```

THE Arduino IDE is the latest version (2.0.3). The ESP was installed via the Board Manager as recommended in the ESP docs ([link](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/installing.html)).

I have configured the Arduino IDE as follow:

*Board: ESP32 S3 DevModule   |    UsbMode: USB-OTG*

Does S3Wroom integrated USB support send serial data via USB? If yes, do you have any tips on what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have "USB CDC On Boot" enabled?

Comment: No. Is that needed? What is it? :)

Comment: Double check the baud rate of your serial console. IIRC the bootup baud rate of the ESP32 is 115200, but your program declares the serial bus at 9600. This could explain why you see the bootup messages but not your program outputs.

Comment: USB CDC On Boot will enable the ESP32-S3 native USB as a serial device. It will enable serial output from the ESP32 to the host over its (native) USB.

Comment: I did both things, and now it works! I had to enable CDC and change the baudrate to 115200. Whoever creates an answer I will mark it. Thank you very muchh!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select

`Enable` on the Menu `Tools` >> `USB CDC On boot`

upload the sketch to the ESP32 and it should be working.

Here's a [good tutorial](https://www.hackster.io/hanguyen92205/program-debug-esp32s3-via-usb-serial-onchip-with-arduino-eeead3) about it.